# Joint Probability Density Function

Tags: probability

Given the Joint PDF $f(x,y)=3/4x^3y^2$ $0\le x\le 2$ and $0\le y\le 1$ find $P(X<Y^2)$

I have $$\int^2_0\int^1_0\frac34x^3y^2dydx$$

But should it be written with the x as the lower bound since I am finding the probability that $X$ is less than $Y^2$?$$\int^2_0\int^1_x\frac34x^3y^2dydx$$

Answer (score 1):

**Draw** the rectangle on which the joint density function "lives."

**Draw** carefully the parabola $x=y^2$. The only interesting part is the half $y=\sqrt{x}$. Note that the parabola meets the line $y=1$ at the point $(1,1)$.

We want the probability that $Y\gt \sqrt{X}$. So we want to find the probability that $(X,Y)$ lands in the part $K$ of the rectangle which is above the parabola. The answer is 
$$\iint_K \frac{3}{4}x^3y^2\,dy\,dx.$$
Express this as an *iterated integral*. It does not matter a whole lot the order in which we integrate. If you want to integrate first with respect to $y$ (that is not my first choice) then $y$ goes from $\sqrt{x}$ to $1$, and then $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

If you integrate first with respect to $x$, then $x$ goes from $0$ to $y^2$, and then $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

For the sake of practice, you might want to do it both ways.

Whichever order you choose, the picture gives you the limits of integration.